# Sublime Text 2 + Eval in REPL: Handle is Invalid

Tags: f#, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Using sublime text 2 on windows 8, I've set my key-bindings to:

```
[
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"],
    "args": {
        "id": "repl_f#",
        "file": "config/F/Main.sublime-menu"
    },
    "command": "run_existing_window_command"
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+enter"],
    "args": {
        "scope": "selection"
    },
    "command": "repl_transfer_current"
}
```

]

But when I press "ctrl+shift+enter" I get the following error. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 356, in run_
  File ".\text_transfer.py", line 123, in run
  File ".\sublimerepl.py", line 437, in find_repl
  File ".\repls\subprocess_repl.py", line 185, in is_alive
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 705, in poll
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 874, in _internal_poll
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with another key mapping?

Comment: @AGS No, I do not get the same error with any other key mapping.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to solve the problem - but see these two SublimeREPL issues [#271](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/271) and [#312](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/312).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was able to "solve" the issue by mapping the key-binding to another configuration, specifically `alt+enter`